# Crop and Resize image via Marquee 

Tags: php, jquery, image, jquery-plugins

Is there a jquery plugin that allow me to use Marquee on the image to crop on the specific area and then resize to fixed width and height of image (200 x 100 px).  I understand that  I may need to use PHP for resizing and crop.

I can write code in PHP to upload large poster (jpeg) on the web but I need to find a way to crop and resize via Marquee.. is there a tool for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is what you want:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-jquery-image-cropping-plug-in-from-scratch-part-ii/

**NOTE:**
This is just the Jquery portion of your entire script... PHP should take care of the rest!